# where to introduce deferred function in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object with validate property and that property function send request to server to test.

```
    //clsAjax.js file where i access request function
    request: function(cmd, callback){
        _sendReq(cmd, callback);
    }



//Definition
    obj = {
        title : 'name',
        validation : function(this){
            this.valid = false;
            clsAjax.request('duplicate', function(){
                if(response == true){
                    this.valid = true;
                    console.log(this.valid);
                }
           });
       }
    }



//function call
    form.validation(obj);
    console.log(obj.valid); // It always have false value
```

validation function receive true but before that it executed validation false line.

I want it to wait till ajax finish execution.

How to do that??

Thank.

Comment: _sendReq return a promise??

Comment: Waiting till AJAX finishes would lag the whole page. The callbacks exists so that you can do something else while waiting (javascript has only one thread and it can't execute 2 functions at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your code.

#### 1. `this` generally refers to object to which a function was assigned

So if you do this:

```
var obj = {num: 1234, func: function() {console.log(this);}};
obj.func();
```

You get this output:

[image: image description]

And it works same with your function:

```
clsAjax.request('duplicate', function(){...});
```

There are two workarounds:

1. Create reference to `this` before creating the callback:

   ```
   var _this = this;
   clsAjax.request('duplicate', function(){_this.valid = true;});
   ```
2. Use HTML5 `Function.prototype.bind` - that changes meaning of `this` in a function:

   ```
   var callback = function(){this.valid = true;}.bind(this);
   clsAjax.request('duplicate', callback);
   ```

#### 1. There is no point to query the value before the callback has returned

```
form.validation(obj);
console.log(obj.valid); // It always have false value
```

When you do `console.log(obj.valid)` your callback wasn't called yet because it's still communicating with the server.

Comment: You are right, how to stop execution at.........   till it finish communicating with server??

Comment: Do not do that. It will lag the whole browser. Just use the callback. You must learn that this is the way javascript works. You assign functions that run when something is done, you do not stop execution. Look in the javascript question list, you'll see you're not the only one who has problems understanding the way javascript handles async operations.